# How to migrate a question to another SE?

Tags: discussion, bug

So it seems like this question https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9618/what-kind-of-land-and-weather-is-required-to-cultivate-apples should be migrated to gardening. I guess the correct procedure in this case is to vote to close, select "off-topic", then "belongs on another SE", and then choose from the options. However, when I get to that point, the only option I'm given is migrating to meta.biology. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't have any migration paths enabled, migration to other SE sites is only possible for moderators. To get a question migrated just flag it for moderator attention.

Migration paths are usually only enabled between non-beta sites, and only if there is a significant number of migrated questions.

Comment: Got it, thanks! It seems like not understanding the beta/graduated distinction was my main problem.